# Issue with React deployment on AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: java, reactjs, spring, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a simple app with Java and Spring backend and React frontend. This app works fine in my local, but I have a problem with the React part when I deploy it on AWS Elastic Beanstalk.

The app contains 2 modules backend and frontend under the main one. The backend module contains Controller with an endpoint and Frontend module includes React part that just fetches that endpoint and adds a header + changes style. Code snippets are below. This app works as it should when I run it on my local by running the backend application and npm start for React.

But after I deployed it on AWS Elastic Beanstalk I can see "Start page" title in a web browser but without a header and new style. So I suppose that React part doesn't work for some reason on AWS in my case.

**More details about what I've deployed:**
I uploaded .jar file, that was built with Maven.
[backend target folder content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nPqv9.png)

My backend .pom contains build settings, that allow to collect React build folder into the target folder for backend part while maven install.
[target folder content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cI9II.png)

So, I suppose that React should be deployed and work the same way as in my local. But it seems that I am missing some setting part in my code or in AWS configurations.

Please help me to recognize the exact problem and solution.
Please, feel free to ask me for more details if you needed.

**Controller:**

```
@RestController
@CrossOrigin
@RequestMapping()
public class StartPageController {

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String startPage() {
        return "Start page";
    }

}
```

**React App.js :**

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import './App.css';

function App () {
    const [message, setMessage] = useState("");

    useEffect(() => {
        // fetch('https://*mywebsite*.com/api/v1/hello')
        fetch('https://*mywebsite*.com')
            .then(response => response.text())
            .then(message => {
                setMessage(message);
            });
    },[])
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <header className="">
                <h1>React is here!</h1>
                <h2 className="App-title">{message}</h2>
            </header>
        </div>
    )
}

export default App;
```

Actually I also have more complicated endpoints and logic that also works fine in my local, but  the same result on AWS - backend works fine, but no React running. So I've started just with this simple example to recognize what is happening.

I have seen some tutorials and explanations how to deploy Spring Boot app or React or how to deploy React in S3 bucket and Java app on AWS EB, but it seems that it should be an option how to deploy them together on AWS EB.

**UPDATE:**

Following @MarkB advice, I've tested .jar in my local and refactored some code. After that I successfully deployed this code on AWS. But I still have some issue with React connection with a Backend part.

If I have the next controller and use `fetch('https://*mywebsite*.com')` in App.js mentioned above, I see just "Start page" string on https://*mywebsite*.com. Without React features.

```
    @RestController
    @CrossOrigin
    @RequestMapping(path = "/")
    public class StartPageController {
    
        @GetMapping()
        public String startPage() {
            return "Start page";
        }
    
    }
```

If I comment out controller above from my code and leave the next controller with `fetch('https://*mywebsite*.com/api/v1/hello')` in App.js, I see "React is here!" string + "Hello Everyone !" string on https://*mywebsite*.com

```
    @RestController
    @CrossOrigin
    @RequestMapping(path = "api/v1")
    public class BasicController {
    
        @GetMapping("/hello")
        public String sayHello() {
            return "Hello Everyone !";
        }
    
    }
```

And one more stranger thing for me - in the same last case if I go directly to the https://*mywebsite*.com/api/v1/hello, I see just "Hello Everyone !" string without React features.

So, for now I have 3 questions:

1. Why React part doesn't work with "/" endpoint?
2. Why the last case shows me React features on main domain name and doesn't show it on /api/v1/hello path that it fetches in App.js?
3. As I understand AWS should make health check for "/" endpoint. So why it still works when I comment out controller that works with this endpoint?

Comment: You are testing locally using two running processes, Java and Node. On ElasticBeanstalk you are only deploying the Java app. You aren't actually testing your deployment artifact before you try deploying it to AWS. You need to take that .jar file that you are building and try to run it locally. If it doesn't work then you aren't including your React build in the Spring app correctly, or you haven't configured Spring to serve the static resources correctly. You need to test and get it working locally before even attempting to deploy to AWS.

Comment: @MarkB thank you, that is right, it also did't work when I run .jar in my local. I've refactored the code and run .jar in my local. And it seems that React doesn't work with "/" endpoint for some reason. For example if I use @GetMapping("/api") it returns me a value with React features, but if I change it to @GetMapping("/") it just returns me value without React features. But I need @GetMapping("/") endpoint for AWS to pass a health check , as I understand. As the AWS expert do you know where I can change health check configurations and what is the best practice for that?

Comment: If your only problem is the health check, don't modify your application to pass a health check, modify the health check settings on your Elastic Beanstalk load balancer. What specifically about your current `/` endpoint is causing a health check to fail?

Comment: @MarkB thank you for your support! I didn't change anything on AWS, just checked and changed some code to be sure that it works the same way on AWS and in my local. And have new questions related to this case. I think mostly from React perspective, but from AWS perspective too. I've updated my post. Could you take a look, please?

Comment: This is no longer about AWS Elastic Beanstalk. I think you need to post a new question asking how to bundle a React app into a Spring Boot application.